# Discussion Forum - Change order of fields?

Tags: column, discussion-board

The Team Site template provides a default Team Discussion link. The New Discussion screen has Subject and Body input fields by default.

Using the Discussion Board Settings, I was able to create a new input list called "Category".  While creating a new discussion entry, my screen shows:

```
Subject - textbox
Body - multiline text
Category - list
```

I want to arrange this screen/form to display Category list on top.  The new screen should look like:

```
Category - list
Subject - textbox
Body - multiline text
```

How can I achieve this OOTB?

Comment: This is inaccurate for SharePoint 2010. A discussion forum does not give this function option to order the fields. The order fields on lists functions in the way you mentioned, but the Discussion Board does not. Unfortunately, I'm facing a issue right now where I need to re-order the Discussion Board and I'm struggling to find a way to do it since SP doesn't have the column order function available. :-(

Comment: can't see the column ordering. not even the manage content. pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to be an easy one.  If you go to the List Settings, right below that list of columns in the list, you should see a link for 'Column ordering'.  Whatever order you put the columns in there will be the order you see them in the forms.

Answer (score 2):

In case the option is not visible, add this link to your browser http://yousite.com/_layouts/formEdt.aspx?List=YourLidtID

Answer (score 0):

I did find a fix....for me, the "Manage Content Types" was turned on by default. When it is turned on, the "Column Ordering" option is not available. Once I turned the "Column Ordering" off, and went to list options, I was able to re-order my discussion board form.

Comment: did you mean that you turned "Manage content types" off?